# Sharing unit test code from two different branch in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, branch

I have two different TFS branch which needs to share some code . This is to make sure that all the teams are using the same code. This will also reduce maintenance. I am not very sure how should I do it.

EDIT: The code does not get shipped to the customers.

The only solution I can think of right now is to create a separate solution in one of the branch with the common code and add the resulting assembly in that branch. Other branch can checkout this assembly and add the assembly in their projects. This does not seems to be a proper solution.

The code will be in one branch and others can not modify it.
Also in this case if one team makes some changes to the code the other will be unaware of the changes. Others need to be notified of the change.

Is their any easier and proper solution to this?

Edit: the code that need to be shared is unit test code. we are going to run it before the build

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, NuGet package is the way to go!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think about creation of separate TFS project with common code and NuGet package using Build server. If someone make any changes in common component Build server create new NuGet package which will be downloaded during build by other solutions.
However such solution needs some Proof-Of-Concept and it depends how many changes could be done in common code base.